# Conditional template specialization on method of a non template class

Tags: c++, templates, boost, template-specialization, enable-if

I am trying to use boost::enable_if to conditional specialize a method of a non-templated class, but failing at it.

```
//OSSpecific.h
...
//If some OS
typedef unsigned int UINT;
//else
typedef unsigned long long UINT;
...

//Foo.h
...
#include <OSSpecific.h>
...
class Foo
{
   public:
          ...
          template <typename T>
          returnThis<T>* bar();
}
/******************************************************************/
//Foo.cpp
...
template<>
returnThis<float>* bar()
{
}

//Use this if some condition is true
template<>
returnThis<int>* Foo::bar<boost::disable_if_c<boost::is_same<int, UINT>::value >::type>()
{
    //Do something
}

    //Use this if some condition is true
template<>
returnThis<long long>* Foo::bar<boost::disable_if_c<boost::is_same<long long, UINT>::value >::type>()
{
    //Do something
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Foo.cpp : error C2785: 'returnType<T> *Foo::bar(void)' and 'returnType<T> *Foo::bar(void)' have different return types         
            with                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                T=int                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
            ]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            Foo.h : see declaration of 'Foo::bar'                                                
            Foo.cpp : see declaration of 'Foo::bar'                                                                                                                     
    Foo.cpp : error C2910: 'Foo::bar' : cannot be explicitly specialized
```

Any pointers where I am going wrong?

**EDIT**: I tried to simplify my question too much. Adding more relevant detail.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish here. `boost::is_same<int, long>::type` will always be `integral_constant<bool, false>`.

Comment: I want to disable if `int` and `long` are the same type. Fixed.

Comment: But... `int` and `long` are never the same type, even if they are the same width on a particular platform.

Comment: But they are never the same type, even if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must follow ODR - one definition rule. So you have to have declarations of your functions also in header file.
2. To use SFINAE your functions need to be template functions - not fully specialized template functions - but couple of different template functions.

So - see header file. Note that you have 3 different functions here - they are not specializations of each others. Thanks to SFINAE first is only active if `T==float`. 2nd and 3rd if `T==UINT` - and the distinction between them is this condition: `UINT==unsigned int`.

```
class Foo
{
public:

    template <typename T>
    typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<T,float>,returnThis<float>*>::type 
    bar();

    template <typename T>
    typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_same<T,UINT>::value and boost::is_same<UINT,unsigned int>::value,
    returnThis<UINT>*>::type 
    bar();

    template <typename T>
    typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_same<T,UINT>::value and not boost::is_same<UINT,unsigned int>::value,
             returnThis<UINT>*>::type 
    bar();
};
```

Then possible usage file:

```
int main() {
    Foo f;
    f.bar<float>();
    f.bar<UINT>();
    return 0;
}
```

If `UINT==unsigned int` this code will call 1st and 2nd functions. If `UINT!=usinged int` the 1st and 3rd functions will be called.

Then your source file (Foo.cpp):

```
template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<T,float>,returnThis<float>*>::type 
Foo::bar()
{
    cout << "bar<T==float>()\n";
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_same<T,UINT>::value and boost::is_same<UINT,unsigned int>::value,
returnThis<UINT>*>::type 
Foo::bar()
{
    cout << "bar<T==UINT and UINT==usigned int>()\n";
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_same<T,UINT>::value and not boost::is_same<UINT,unsigned int>::value,
returnThis<UINT>*>::type 
Foo::bar()
{
    cout << "bar<T==UINT and UINT!=usigned int>()\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Since these functions do not actually depends on `T` - you can require from compiler to have generated code in your dedicated cpp file by template explicit instantiation instructions:

```
template returnThis<float>* Foo::bar<float>();
template returnThis<UINT>* Foo::bar<UINT>();
```

See [IDEONE working example](http://ideone.com/GrMVih)

Comment: 1. Where am I running into partial specialization?
2. I want to split up the code in separate H/CPP files.

Comment: @armundle You changed the question. But anyway - you must follow the one definition rule (ODR), otherwise your program is undefined behavior. You cannot have in header file general template function and full specialization in cpp file. You must say in header file (declare) that you will have full specialization.

Comment: @armundle And you cannot use SFINAE for non template function/class - it is not possible.

Comment: Well, the method is templated.

Comment: Don't treat fully specialization template as real template. See my update to answer.